# Changed partition mount settings and can't boot now

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I changed my main partition settings, I just turned on the toggle for User Session Defaults to ON using the Disks utility, and when I reboot my computer it gets stuck on the Ubuntu loading page, with the dots. I am running a dual boot with Windows 10, but I only changed settings for the partition with Ubuntu on it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.